# How to add fields from different source table in a page (NAV 2016)?

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-nav, microsoft-dynamics-nav, dynamics-nav-2016

I want to add fields from Table - "Customer Bank Account" in Page - "Bank Receipt Journal" which has a current source table as "Gen. Journal Line".

It might be helpful if I get to the know the process for adding fields as a lookup from different Table source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it depends on your requirements:

- If you think the additional fields may also be used on other pages that have "Gen. Journal Line" as their SourceTable, I would consider adding  FlowFields of method "Lookup" to your "Gen. Journal Line" table (assuming you have sufficient permissions to do so). In your response, please elaborate on how you want your lookup logic to work for further assistance, if needed.
- If your lookup logic is more complex than FlowFields can handle, a function on the "Gen. Journal Line." that returns the relevant field value may be a good solution.
- Alternatively, if this is the only page where you will need your new fields, or if you don't have permissions to modify table definitions, define a function in your page object that performs the lookup and returns the value. Use this function as the SourceExpr of your page control.

Comment: You have explain it well regarding the flowfields. I have added 'Bank Name' and 'Bank Branch no.' fields in Page - "Bank Receipt Journal". The source of this fields are from Table - "Customer Bank Account". On Page "Bank Receipt Journal" I want this 2 fields should give lookup of 'Bank Name' and 'Bank Branch no.' Respectively. Pls explain me taking this requirement in your view.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the link between your Gen. Journal Line and the Customer Bank Account that you want to display values from should be based on the Recipient Bank Account field in the Gen. Journal Line?

Comment: In that case, my second suggestion is probably best - a function on the Gen. Journal Line. I don't have NAV installed on the machine I'm writing this on, so I'm afraid I cannot give you a sample function.